# Opening tabs using Webbrowser module in Python

Tags: python

I'm writing a Python Script using webbrowser module to automatically open the desired webpages.
The issue I'm facing is that I'm only able to open the webpages on different Browser windows and not on the same Browser window on different tabs.

Below is the code that I'm using.

```
#! /usr/bin/python -tt

import webbrowser

def main():

    webbrowser.open('url1')
    webbrowser.open('url2')
    webbrowser.open('url3')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I want to open all these links on the same web browser window on separate tabs and not on different browser windows.
Thanks  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)`. For example...

```
import webbrowser
url = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com'
url2 = 'http://www.stackexchange.com'

def main():
    webbrowser.open(url2) # To open new window
    print('Opening Stack Exchange website!')
    webbrowser.open_new_tab(url) # To open in new tab
    print('Opening Stack Overflow website in a new tab!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Waiting for 3 mins to get over. It won't allow me to do before 3 mins. I just checked in ;)

Answer (score 3):

In python 3.6, a complete answer will include both `webbrowser.open_new()` and `webbrowser.open_new_tab()` from the [webbrowser docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/webbrowser.html).

```
import webbrowser

def main():
    # print(webbrowser._browsers) # for Python 3.x to determine .get() arg
    browser = webbrowser.get('firefox')

    urls = ['url1', 'url2', 'url3']

    first = True
    for url in urls:
        if first:
            browser.open_new(url)
            first = False
        else:
            browser.open_new_tab(url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Enjoy the code. +1 if it helped you out. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Simply `webbrowser.open_new_tab('url')`