# Script to open multiple Chrome tabs each for a Google search from a list of keywords present in an Excel sheet

Tags: python, excel

I have a list of keywords stored in a column in an Excel sheet. I want to do a Google search for each keyword in separate chrome tabs.

Can anyone please help me with Python code to automate it?

Comment: Rahil, wouldn't this suite your purposes without having to use a Python script? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/open-multiple-urls/oifijhaokejakekmnjmphonojcfkpbbh

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Opening tabs using Webbrowser module in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26114930/opening-tabs-using-webbrowser-module-in-python)

Comment: I noticed you just changed "URLs" to "keywords". Do you mean you want to do a Google search for each keyword?

Comment: yea precisely want to do a google search for each item in the column at once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rahil, say your keywords are in the "A" column of `rahils_keywords.xlsx` file, in the worksheet called `keywords`. At the shell, install this dependency:

```bash
> pip install openpyxl
```

Then in your text editor or Python REPL:

```py
import webbrowser

from openpyxl import load_workbook


def google_search_keywords_from_spreadsheet(path: str, sheet: str, column: str):
    wb = load_workbook(filename=path)
    worksheet = wb[sheet]
    num_rows = worksheet.max_row

    for row_num in range(num_rows):
        cell = f"{column}{row_num + 1}"
        keyword = worksheet[cell].value
        if keyword: # skip blank cells
            url = f"https://google.com/search?q={keyword}"
            print(f'searching for keyword "{keyword}"...')
            webbrowser.open(url)

google_search_keywords_from_spreadsheet(
    path="rahils_keywords.xlsx",
    sheet="keywords",
    column="A",
)
```

Comment: Thanks so much Sir but The code is giving me an error. my excel sheet has only one column and in that column i have n number of urls , i want to open all those urls at once in different chrome tabs. Thanks in advance

Comment: Rahil, what's the error?

Comment: File "c:\Users\Rahil\Desktop\test2.py", line 4
    wb = load_workbook(filename="C:\Users\Rahil\Desktop\search.xlsx")
                                                                    ^        
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: this may not be a panacea, but make sure you're using Python3 -- Python2 is not supported anymore!

Comment: actually have a look here, you may have copy-pasted some unwanted invisible characters: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63292817/4386191

Comment: sure i shall do that thanks for the help and i am using python 3, i shall update you about the same ASAP

Comment: Thank you Sir for the help! the code works!!